# How to increase numbers line by line

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/DtuFHXtmYnUEfbVKB5mf?p=preview)

I have Implemented the above plunker, In that plunker the rowId is increasing with Alphabets.Like the below

There will be `+` and `++` and - buttons in that component.
If I press `+` then The Rowid will start from Starting Alphabet(`A`).
If I press `++` Then The parent rowid + starting with Starting Alphabet means(`AA`). 
And Again if I press `++` then parent rowId + starting with Starting Alphabet means(`AAA`). Like this it will increase.

Please access the [Plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/DtuFHXtmYnUEfbVKB5mf?p=preview)

But I want to achieve that functionality with Numbers means

For single plus it should show `1`, For `++` it should show `111` like this I need to achieve.

Can you please help me to do this functionality.

```
var newRow = {
    "rowId": "A"
  }
  $scope.componentList = [];
  $scope.componentList.push(angular.copy(newRow));

  $scope.addParentRow = function(rowId) {
    var newGridRow = angular.copy(newRow);
    var lastChar = getListOfSameLevel(rowId, true); //isParentRow
    var parentId = rowId.length > 1 ? rowId.slice(0, rowId.length - 1) : "";
    newGridRow.rowId = parentId + getNextChar(lastChar);
    $scope.componentList.push(newGridRow);
  }

  $scope.addChildRow = function(rowId) {
    var newGridRow = angular.copy(newRow);
    var lastChar = getListOfSameLevel(rowId, false);
    if (rowId.length === lastChar.length) {
      newGridRow.rowId = rowId + "A";
    } else {
      var parentId = lastChar.length > 1 ? lastChar.slice(0, lastChar.length - 1) : "";
      newGridRow.rowId = parentId + getNextChar(getLastChar(lastChar));
    }
    $scope.componentList.push(newGridRow);
  };

  var getNextChar = function(inputChar) {
    return String.fromCharCode(inputChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  };

  var getLastChar = function(fullStr) {
    return fullStr.slice(-1);
  };
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. What specifically should be changed into what and what have you tried?

Comment: In That plunker Alphabets are increasing but Need to increase Numbers. Finally Alphabets Need to Replace with Numbers

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. I don't see any numbers in the Plunker and I don't understand where they should be. Have you tried something already yourself? If so it would be helpful to add that code too.

Comment: In the plunker If I press `+` button then rowId will become the next Alphabet. Here I need to replace that Alphabets with numbers.So first rowid will be `1` If i press `+` button it should be 11

Comment: One suggestion, children should be deleted when you delete parent.

Comment: @slacker yeah I will implement the same

Comment: his answer and your plunker too. When I remove parent, children are still there. It shouldn't be the case. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the initial value of **newRow.rowId** from `A` to `1` and to change the initiation of the next digits from `A` to `1` in the **addChildRow** function like this :

```
if (rowId.length === lastChar.length) {
    newGridRow.rowId = rowId + "1";
}
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/GbWBKQuSp0y90ptg5mAn?p=preview) is your plunker with numbers

Comment: But here it is giving special charecters after 9. but I want to continue with 10

Comment: If next number after 109 is 1010, then whats the difference between `+` and `++` on 109?

Comment: In this scenario the rowId is 109, if I press `+` button the number should be 110. If I press `++` then the rowId is 1091

Comment: Yes but it's not a problem if there are multiple ways to get the same number ? By example if you click `+` on the number 110 you get 111 and if you click on `++` on the number 11 you get 111 too !

Comment: yes,, that's good suggestion,, Need to think about this..... But can You please give some suggetion On this scenario.

Comment: I just tried to rephrase what @jsalonen was saying. And to achieve this, I think when you increase the last digit you need to check if it's not equal to 9 char code and instead of increasing it, replace it by 10. Or maybe try to work with number instead of char code

Comment: Yeah sorry was for talking about the same thing, but didn't articulate well. Anyways: its possible to end up with exactly same values that way. Unless you either 1) use a separation character (like `,´ or space) or 2) allow values beyond 9 its not possible to separate them.

Comment: @JeanJacques can we add `P` letter for the parent and `C` for the child

Comment: @Murali Yes, but what will you do for the childs of those childs ?

Comment: @JeanJacques can you please help me to increase the numbers from 9 ==> 10 ==> 11 ...,

Comment: Just use a separator: row ID 11-1 and 1-11 are clearly two different IDs. – Robby Cornelissen

Comment: if I kept `var getNextChar = function(inputChar) {
    return ++inputChar;
  };` then the 10 is adding as a child of 1